# How to "merge" 2 VR180 video files to get a 360 video (2xVR180) output with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm wondering how to actually use ffmpeg to create a 2xVR180 video file from 2 different VR180 videos.
That's to say, on the front side, a stereoscopic 3D video, and on the back side, another stereoscopic 3D video.

Videos are taken with an Insta360 EVO in 3D mode, so I can either deal with 4 video files (2 INSV files for the left eye and other 2 INSV files for the right eye), o directly with the 2 stitched HEVC/MP4 files.

I know the result won't be a 360 3D stereoscopic video, that's why I'm talking about "2xVR180".

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution!

The "algorithm" is :

- Separate left eye from right eye of both video files
- Join both left eyes
- Join both right eyes
- Join left eyes with right eyes
- Resize the video

The resulting is something like :

```
Front left eye | Back left eye | Front right eye | Back right eye
```

To get this using ffmpeg, i used the following syntax

```
ffmpeg -i front_vr180.mp4 -i back_vr180.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=2880:2880:0:0[aleft];[0:v]crop=2880:2880:iw-2880:0[aright];[1:v]crop=2880:2880:0:0[bleft];[1:v]crop=2880:2880:iw-2880:0[bright];[aleft][bleft]hstack=inputs=2[left];[aright][bright]hstack=inputs=2[right];[left][right]hstack=inputs=2[full];[full]scale=7680:-1[v]" -map "[v]" -b:v 200M -preset slow -crf 6 full_360VR_test.mp4
```

I'm chaining the crop filter (eye separation) with the hstack filter (video concatenation) to finally resize the video thanks to the scale filter.

With more details:

- -i front_vr180.mp4 : The VR180 video file I want to see in front of me
- -i back_vr180.mp4 : The VR180 video file I want to see behind me
- -filter_complex : a chain of filters I have to apply to get this working
- [0:v]crop=2880:2880:0:0[aleft]:

  - [0:v] means "First input, video channel" and placed before a filter means that's the input of this filter
  - crop=2880:2880:0:0[aleft] means the input will be cropped to result in a 2880x2880 size from (0,0) (top left corner). In other words, the left square of the first video (video A or front). [aleft] is just a label to identify the result of this filter (left part of video A)
  - Same thing to get the right part of the A video (aright), and both left and right parts of the B video
- [aleft][bleft]hstack=inputs=2[left] That means I will concatenate, side by side, both left eye videos into one unique [left] video. If aleft and bleft were 2880x2880 videos, [left] will be a 5760x2880 video.

  - Same thing with the right eye to get [right] as a 5760x2880 video.
- [left][right]hstack=inputs=2[full] : Same logic as before, [left] and [right] are put together into [full], side by side, to achieve the 3D SBS effect.

At this point, we would have a 2xVR180 video, but size is too huge (11520x2880) and need to be scale down (for instance, 8K).  This is done with [full]scale=7680:-1[v]. 7680 is the width, -1 as height means we let ffmpeg determinate the correct height to keep ratio aspect. The result of this scale down, [v] will be 7680x1920.

- -map "[v]" : means only the video channel is required
- -b:v 200M : this option sets the bitrate. Value depends on the input video files... More bitrate means more details, but if the input have a low bitrate, ffmpeg won't invent details. I chose a bitrate = sum(input bitrates).
- crf 6 : CRF means constant rate factor. 0 = lossless, 51 = worst quality, using x264.
- preset slow: well, I think the ffmepg documentation would be better than me to explain this. More slower, better quality :)